# When use String.Insert(int index, string text) insert at the end of the new string: "00000"

Tags: c#, string, file, insert

I need to insert in a specific position of the string `line`, another string, so I compute the specific position for start to insert:

```
string info1 = "info1";
string info2 = "info2"; 
string info3 = "info3";
string info4 = "info4";
string keyWord = "BELEGIT";

start = line.IndexOf(keyWord, 0) + keyWord.Length + 13;
var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(line);
aStringBuilder.Remove(start, 19);
line = aStringBuilder.ToString();

string newLine =  line.Insert(start, "\r\n" + info1 + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + info2 + "\r\n" + info3 + "\r\n" + info4 + "\r\n");
```

(`newLine` will be the content of a file in my application).

`newline` contains the correct content except the string `"00000"` that inserts after `"info4"`. So in my new file with the content that is `newline` there is `newline` and immediately after `"00000"`. I do not really understand why.
Thanks in advance.

INPUT:
`line` contains:

> #~11\r\nT-02040121R\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\n2.000000000\r\n

OUTPUT
`newLine` contains:

> #~11\r\nT-02040121R\r\ninfo1\r\n\r\ninfo2\r\ninfo3\r\ninfo4\r\n00000\r\n

Comment: Can you please include the sample input and output?

Comment: Please find out what text is in `line`. Please copy it, as text, and paste the text into your question.

Comment: I see that you are hardcoding everything in this process. you should stop doing that. where numbers `13` and `19` come from? is that a contract? length of some other string? you should **at least** store them in a field with a descriptive name of what it represents or what its intended for.

Comment: @un-lucky Of Course: should be:                                                       "#~11
T-02040121R
info1
info2
info3
info4
2.000000000"                                                                                                                    instead I obtain:                                                                                                 "#~11
T-02040121R
info1
info2
info3
info4
00000"                                                                                                                  substituting the 7 line of the file with 00000

Comment: @NoeDag and the sample input? You should post input and output in your question.

Comment: I guess that "00000" is not because of using String.Insert(int index, string text). I think this text is just presented in your original `line`

Comment: The content of `line` would help, too.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I'm trying to edit my post to insert the input but I can't. My "line" is the content of a file that I have to edit in "newLine"

Comment: @NoeDag What is the problem you are having editing your question? Click the "edit" link immediately below your question, on the left hand side. Then paste in the text.

Comment: Like Roman Koliada said, maybe the `00000`is already in `line` but it's just a guess without knowing the content of it. Why you can't edit your question?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom 
sorry, I forgot to insert the most importat thing, I just edit my post and entered my input

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You are removing `\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\n2.000000`(19 characters starting from the 19 position. 19 = -1 + 7 + 13) but `000\r\n` is still there. So you also have it the `newline`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want just the first 19 chars of `line`you could use `Substring`to get them and `string.Format`to build the new `string`.

Something like this

```
var start = line.Substring(0, 19);
string newLine = $"{start}\r\n{info1}\r\n\r\n{info2}\r\n{info3}\r\n{info4}\r\n";
```

The second line is the short form for

```
string newLine = string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n\r\n{2}\r\n{3}\r\n{4}\r\n", start, info1, info2, info3, info4);
```

if you need more information about `string.Format`have a look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).